# Installing Django+MySql on mac

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I have been trying to install Django and mysql on my mac for days and it is driving me crazy :)
I have successfully installed Django on 2 of my other mac machines but I can’t manage to do that on MacBook Pro with latest os. 
I have installed Python 3.6 in Anaconda virtual environment. Then I installed mysql using `brew install mysql@5.7`, I have installed Django using `pip install django==2` and even `pip install mysqlclient`
When i try to run `python manage.py` i am getting:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
>   Did you install mysqlclient?

I have tried to install mysql@5.6 with brew but i have uninstalled it.

Can somebody please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Anaconda Distribution for Mac https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos
and then you can install the Django and MYSQL Client using the following commands.

```
conda install -c anaconda django
conda install -c anaconda mysqlclient
```

Comment: Wow, this solved everything. I have tried so many ways and read so many answers here on StackOverflow but your answer solved at least 5 days of struggling. Thank you very very much!